# Parsing russian site encoding error

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, encoding, beautifulsoup

There is a problem with the encoding when parsing the site https://beton24.ru/sochi/beton/

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen('https://beton24.ru/sochi/beton/')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
result = bs.findAll("span", "catalog-index__link-text")[1]
parse = str(result)
```

To get the price of concrete, I convert the result to str, and it turns into 'from \ xa03 \ u2009836 \ xa0₽'

Who faced, how to solve? Thank you!

Comment: What were you expecting instead?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov `urllib.request` indicates Python 3, as does a `str` containing `\u` escapes.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is:

```
parse = result.text
```